# Pasting/Copying a Sketch onto a Drawing

Tags: freecad

I have a sketch and a blank drawing made using using the A3 template and want to paste/copy/insert the sketch on to the drawing.

However I seem to be missing something because there are no useful-looking active menu options or buttons available in either the drawing or the sketch that would allow adding the sketch to the drawing.

I tried both the online docs and a couple of youtube tutorials, but am apparently doing something wrong because I can't get the merge to happen.

Can anybody give me a hint or point me to a tutorial on how to get a 2D sketch into a drawing?

This is FreeCAD 0.17 on Fedora.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeCAD has two different workbenches for producing technical drawings.  The Drawing workbench is older and being replaced with TechDraw.  You didn't say which you're trying to use but I'll assume TechDraw:

1) Switch to the TechDraw workbench
2) Insert a new default drawing
3) Select the sketch in the tree
4) Insert a view of the sketch in to the drawing (toolbar or menu)

If you're using the older Drawing workbench, the process is about the same but the view may be being placed outside the bounds of the page.  Open the page node in the tree, select the view, and adjust the XY properties until the view appears.

One caveat;  Many people are confused about the purpose of the sketcher.  The 'constraints' that you apply are NOT dimensions and will not appear in the drawing page (either TechDraw or Drawing workbench).  The constraints are purely used internally to drive the geometry.

If you want to reproduce dimensions in a drawing, definitely use Techdraw and then apply dimensions in that workbench.

Comment: Thank you! 

I have no idea why, but now the grayed out buttons are enabled and the "Insert new view" button worked!

Comment: Just a note in case anybody else runs into this: I downgraded to the 0.16 that comes with my current Fedora distribution and it started to behave much more predictably. It might be a bug or it's equally possible that I just don't understand 0.17.